# Постоянное отслеживание позиции элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `div` 
, который меняет свое положение относительно страницы по разным причинам, а потому отследить событие через `click` или `change` нельзя.

Как постоянно (или с интервалом) отслеживать положение этого элемента, чтобы предположим при достижении параметра `top` меньше `100px` запускалось определенное действие?

Comment: "По разным причинам" - он же меняет свое положение при помощи JS-функции? Повесьте в конец ее выполнения проверку положения элемента. Иначе придется запускать бесконечный setInterval, а это вряд ли хорошая идея.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В jQuery нет события об изменении позиции элемента. 
Можно написать функцию для отслеживания изменения позиции через интервалы времени:

```
function watch ($el, func, interval) {
  if (!interval) interval = 200;        
  var prevOffset = $el.offset();      
  setInterval(function () {
      var offset = $el.offset();
      if (prevOffset.top != offset.top || prevOffset.left != offset.left) {
          prevOffset = offset;
          func.call($el[0], offset);
      }
  }, interval);
}
```

Вызвать так:

```
watch($('div'), function (offset) {
  if (offset.top <= 100) {
    //код
  }
});
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/yt3s4oaf/)

Comment: а есть возможность модифицировать ваш код, чтобы расчет top считался от верхней границы видимой части экрана, а не от начала документа?

Comment: Нужно использовать [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/). Нужно вычесть `$(window).scrollTop()` из `offset.top`. [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/yt3s4oaf/1/)